# URDF model frames not published properly by robot_state_publisher

Tags: urdf, ros-kinetic, frames, xacro, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I'm struggling with getting a URDF (or XACRO file to be exact) working with the robot_state_publisher. I know that it has been working when I made the file originally, but after updating and getting back to this project I simply can not get the robot_state_publisher to publish all the frames correctly.

You find the XACRO file as part of my repository here: https://github.com/mindThomas/JetsonCar-Simulation/blob/master/jetsoncar_description/urdf/jetsoncar.xacro

Try and clone the repository and build it with catkin and then run the rviz launch file. Or you can try and just run the robot_state_publisher on the xacro file output.
Running a TF view_frames on the published frames gives the following incorrect result:

[image description http://www.tkjelectronics.dk/uploads/ROS_URDF_FrameProblem.png](http://www.tkjelectronics.dk/uploads/ROS_URDF_FrameProblem.png)

It seems like the problem is related to the revolute or continuous joints. At least if I replace these joints with fixed joints the frames are published correctly.

PS. I'm running ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04.

Best regards,
Thomas Jespersen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285145/urdf-model-frames-not-published-properly-by-robot_state_publisher/) by [mindthomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/29887/mindthomas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2018-03-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-12**:
Your problem is that you don't have all your tf published (those linked to the shafts) ?

**Comment by [mindthomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/29887/mindthomas/) on 2018-03-12**:
Yes, agreed. But why doesn't the robot_state_publisher handle these missing ones (attached to the shafts) when the node seems to be publishing all the frames from the same URDF file nicely?

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-12**:
Well it's embarassing because when I run your code I had those tf published so it's not a problem with your code. I ran `roslaunch jetsoncar_description rviz.launch` and then `rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-12**:
What does "can not get the robot_state_publisher to publish all the frames correctly"? What are we supposed to see? Please describe that in your question text.

**Comment by [mindthomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/29887/mindthomas/) on 2018-03-13**:
@delb If I try to run `rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree` I get a segmentation fault.

@gvdhoorn You are supposed to see both left and right bearings and wheels attached to the front shaft and left and right wheels attached to the rear shaft.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-13**:
[Here](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/11/2/1520952348-tf-tree.png) is what I get with your urdf and `rqt_tf_tree` so you clearly have another issue. Try to do a simple urdf with multiples links to see if you have them all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem has been solved by uninstalling/removing Anaconda.
I don't know how Anaconda managed to mess up the runtime execution.

Any suggestions how to install and use Anaconda next to a well working ROS Kinetic environment?

---

Originally posted by [mindthomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/29887/mindthomas/) with karma: 61 on 2018-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0